# Qlabel with image using QPixmap

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wanted to include a QToolbar in a Qwidget, but I found that I can only create a QToolbar in a QMainWindow. So, instead I want to create a Qlabel with an arrow icon in it. I downloaded an [image with transparent background](https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow%20blue%20icons&sxsrf=ACYBGNSZOyZ-VTwrSxkNFNzmFVFFZXM-VQ:1574676911858&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRmt7PkIXmAhVMwzgGHU5rAbYQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1366&bih=607#imgrc=zMljGwXfNOef6M) (I suppose). But, in the code, the image is not really transparent as I expected, it looks ugly. Is there any way to show only the arrow without the background. Below is a sample code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'test'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Create first tab
        label3 = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap("index2.png")
        smaller_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(32, 32, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        label3.setPixmap(smaller_pixmap)        
        label3.mouseReleaseEvent = self.on_click

        self.layout.addWidget(label3)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self, event):
        print('yes')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: To help others to solve your problem, please include the exact image you downloaded and not a link of a google search. Also, maybe it could help if you post not only the image of the arrow but also a screenshot to show how it looks when its implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this is a first post for me. Next time I shall be more specific.

Comment: Glad to help, that's what this community is for ;) Since you are a new member, it would probably be helpful to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post a question until you get used to what info is needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an "ugly" image because that image has lines that are *partially* transparent. I've increased the alpha threshold to better show them:

[image: Image with alpha changed]

Those lines are part of the image and Qt cannot "guess" what portions of the image are "important" to you or not.
There's fundamentally no easy way to remove them by code, and even you'd succeed the result would be ugly anyway (some partial transparency is required around the border of the image to keep them smooth) and it wouldn't be worth the effort.

Just look for a different image, or edit it by clipping it to the arrow borders.

Comment: Those lines are there because the icons are not free. If you purchase them, they won't have the lines. It's probably not a good idea to attempt to remove them. If you don't intend to purchase them, I would advise using a free site (such as [findicons](https://findicons.com/)) instead, which will allow you to search for icons with non-restrictive licenses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. This is really helpful